# How to show some items in css grid, until see more button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, css

I have a css grid with multiple items, each row has three or four grid areas.  How do I display one row (or first three or four items), followed by a "see more" button?  That button would then show the next set of items, followed by the "see more" button and so on.

Currently I am only able to load all of the grid items at once as a full grid.

Here is the css for the grid:

```
.grid-rp{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 2em;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Here is the grid content for two items as an example:

```
<div class="grid-rp">
  <div class="rp-details">
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><h3>Title</h3></a>
    <p>content goes here</p>
  </div>

  <button class="show-more">Show More</button>

  <div class="rp-details">
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><h3>Title</h3></a>
    <p>content goes here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need help with the JS for the button.

I would like to click on the Load More button and have the next content area be shown.  Until the click that content should be hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind a click event handler and toggle a class(provide the CSS for hiding) on click.

```js
// get button and bind click event handler
document.querySelector('.show-more').addEventListener('click', function() {
  // get rp-detail element which is sibling to the button
  // and then toggle the class
  this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle('hidden')
})
```

```css
.grid-rp {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 2em;
  margin: 0;
}


/* style for hiding */

.rp-details.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-rp">
  <div class="rp-details">
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <h3>Title</h3>
    </a>
    <p>content goes here</p>
  </div>

  <button class="show-more">Show More</button>

  <div class="rp-details hidden">
  <!-- set class here ---^^^^^^---->
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <h3>Title</h3>
    </a>
    <p>content goes here</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE :** If there are multiple elements and button position is somewhere else then do it like.

```js
// get button and bind click event handler
document.querySelector('.show-more').addEventListener('click', function() {
  // get rp-detail element with toggle class
  // then iterate and toggle class of each element
  document.querySelectorAll('.rp-details.toggle').forEach(ele => ele.classList.toggle('hidden'))
})
```

```css
.grid-rp {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 2em;
  margin: 0;
}


/* style for hiding */

.rp-details.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-rp">
  <div class="rp-details">
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <h3>Title</h3>
    </a>
    <p>content goes here</p>
  </div>

  <div class="rp-details hidden toggle">
    <!-- set class here ---^^^^^^---->
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <h3>Title</h3>
    </a>
    <p>content goes here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="rp-details hidden toggle">
    <!-- set class here ---^^^^^^---->
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <h3>Title</h3>
    </a>
    <p>content goes here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="rp-details hidden toggle">
    <!-- set class here ---^^^^^^---->
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <h3>Title</h3>
    </a>
    <p>content goes here</p>
  </div>
  <div class="rp-details hidden toggle">
    <!-- set class here ---^^^^^^---->
    <a href="#" target="_blank">
      <h3>Title</h3>
    </a>
    <p>content goes here</p>
  </div>
</div>

<button class="show-more">Show More</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I tried this set up and it works for the one content area after the button.  How can I load three content areas at once with the button?  Also, how can I have the button load the content before the button in the grid?  This would allow for the button to always stay at the end of the grid.

Comment: Pranav, thank you for the update, but this doesn't seem to be working.  Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Pranav, here is the link to the code you set up in jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/iisrael/koyz74fr/1/

Comment: @Iisrael :  ok let me check

Comment: @Iisrael : ooops found the issue ... missing `s` here `('.rp-detail.toggle')` => `('.rp-details.toggle')`

Comment: Pranav, thanks for checking that works for sure!  I hate to press my luck here, but what if I only wanted to load the next 2 items with each press of the button?  Sorry, I really am starting my work with JS and seem to not know anything.  Also, do you have any suggestions on resources for learning how to use the elements you showed in your code?